# Mapping data coming from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, mapping

I want to map the data for this app. I can't see the data in the browser window in Reactjs. I tried this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../css/Section.css";

const OfferSection = () => {

    const [offer,setOffer] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      
            const textdes = async () => {
              const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL}`).then(
                (response) => response.json()
              );
              setOffer(response);
            };
            textdes();
    },[])
    
    return(
        <div>
            {offer.map((item) => {
                {item.payload.map((ip) => {
                    return (
                        <img src={ip.data.section2.data[0].image} />
                    ) 
                })}
            })}

        </div>
    )
}

export default OfferSection;
```

I want data from this API:

```
http://192.168.1.175:5000/api/home
```

Comment: Did you try to log what's in `offer` ?
Is it possible to have a sample of the data ?

Comment: Also, check your console, are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Write down the function outside of useEffect and then call it inside UseEffect.

console the response log to see data is comming from API or not

```
const textdes = async () => {
          const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL}`).then(
            (response) => response.json()
          );
console.log(response);
         return response;
        };

useEffect(() => {
   textdes().then((res) => setOffer(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
},[]}
```